# Cannot download datasets files from Kaggle to Google Colab

Tags: google-colaboratory

def load_kaggle_csv(dataset_name, file_name):
dataset_url = f"https://www.kaggle.com/{dataset_name}/download"
!kaggle datasets download -d $dataset_url -f $file_name
return pd.read_csv(file_name)

dataset_name = "datasets/diegosilvadefrana/2023-data-scientists-jobs-descriptions"
file_name = "Jobs.csv"

### Error:
Invalid dataset specification https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/diegosilvadefrana/2023-data-scientists-jobs-descriptions/download

FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
9 file_name = "Jobs.csv"
10
---> 11 df = load_kaggle_csv(dataset_name, file_name)

8 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/pandas/io/common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
700         if ioargs.encoding and "b" not in ioargs.mode:
701             # Encoding
--> 702             handle = open(
703                 handle,
704                 ioargs.mode,

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Jobs.csv'

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround:

! kaggle datasets download diegosilvadefrana/2023-data-scientists-jobs-descriptions